# Unable to update github file using CRUD API (using github-flask/python)

Tags: python, github, flask

I am not able to update a file using github-flask.

It gives me a 404 error (https://developer.github.com/v3/troubleshooting/#why-am-i-getting-a-404-error-on-a-repository-that-exists) but I have verified that my auth token is good and has repo scope. I verified so by

```
Anshu-MacBook-Pro:~ anshup$ curl -H "Authorization: token mytoken" https://api.github.com/users/anshprat -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Fri, 11 Jul 2014 07:21:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4991
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1405065424
Cache-Control: private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Jul 2014 06:25:54 GMT
ETag: "etag"
X-OAuth-Scopes: repo
```

My code is:

```
def git_push(file_path,file_path_s,commit_message,raw_file_data):
    u_file_data = base64.b64encode(raw_file_data,salt())
    #print u_file_data
    params = {
            'path':file_path_s
            'message':commit_message,
            'content':u_file_data,
            'sha':file_sha  #Its a global variable
        }
    #print raw_file_data,u_file_data,params
    params_json = json.dumps(params)
    return github.post(file_path,params_json) #params fails as well
```

The flask frame dumps shows:

```
resource    'repos/anshprat/git-test/contents/play1.txt'

status_code '404'

self    <flask_github.GitHub object at 0x2733b90>

response    <Response [404]>

kwargs  {'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 'data': '"{\\"content\\": \\"dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQxCnVzZXIyOnBhc3N3b3JkMgp1c2VyMzpNQlpvRDJLOWJQQS9vCg==\\", \\"sha\\": \\"ce4979fccba7ef259910c355ca6e1993d7ea436c\\", \\"message\\": \\"modifying user user3\\"}"'  }

method  'POST'
```

If I use params in the post, the double quotes are not escaped.
POST also fails for me on curl, so I think I am doing something very basic wrong out here?

```
     curl -H "Authorization: token mytoken" --data  '{"content": "dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQxCnVzZXIyOnBhc3N3b3JkMgp1c2VyMzpEQXR2VUNweUJrbjdFCg==", "message": "modifying user user3", "sha": "ce4979fccba7ef259910c355ca6e1993d7ea436c"}' https://api.github.com/repos/anshprat/git-test/contents/play1.txt
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

github.get for the same file_path works.

The API is listed at

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file

My app should be doing a code commit and then deploy it to some other non github related work.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the github-flask library. I modified it a bit following the implementation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888832/github-api-update-a-file-in-php/ and it seems to be better now. Will update here with solution and a pull request to library after more testing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change

```
def post(self, resource, data, **kwargs):
    """Shortcut for ``request('POST', resource)``.
    Use this to make POST request since it will also encode ``data`` to
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' format."""
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

to

```
def post(self, resource, data, **kwargs):
    """Shortcut for ``request('POST', resource)``.
    Use this to make POST request since it will also encode ``data`` to
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' format."""
    headers = {}
    headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    headers['X-HTTP-Method-Override'] = 'PUT'
```

for it work correctly.